# Rendering children in React, losing props data

Tags: javascript, properties, nested, reactjs, children

I have three react components rendering checkbox groups.

```
Queries -> renders a group
Query -> renders checkboxes
QueryItem -> render single input[type=checkbox]
```

I pass down the data coming from **Queries** as props for the children:

```
<div className="group queries">
  {component.state.groups.map((group, index) => {
    return <Query key={group.key} data={group} />
  })}
</div>
```

Then in **Query**:

```
<div>
  <h1>{component.props.data.label}</h1>

  <ul>
    {component.props.data.queries.map( (query, index) => {
      return <QueryItem key={query.key} data={query} />
    })}
  </ul>
</div>
```

And finally in the **QueryItem** component:

```
<li>
  <input type='checkbox'
    ref="input"
    defaultChecked={component.props.data.checked}
    onChange={component.checkChanged}
    name={component.props.data.id}
    id={component.props.data.id} />

  <label htmlFor={component.props.data.id}>
    {component.props.data.label} <em>({component.props.data.total})</em>
  </label>
</li>
```

The data gets rendered correctly. However, when the onChange (checkChanged function) gets invoked:

```
checkChanged (e) {
  console.log(component.props.data)
}
```

the data in `component.props.data` is the data from the last QueryItem that was rendered. So, basically, the data is always the same and does not represent the data that was rendered.

You can see, I use the key attribute to make sure the component is unique. If I inspect the `data-reactid`, I can see they are unique.

What is going on? What am I doing wrong in the type of setup?
Goal of this setup is to invoke a data-call when a checkbox is changed and then trickling down the data from Queries to Query to QueryItem.

Comment: Does `component` refer to `this`?

Comment: @Morhaus yes, I'm sorry, it does refer to this.

Comment: This sounds to me like some kind of "by-reference" issue, or accidentally sharing scope between component instances via closure.Your use of 'component' instead of 'this' is a likely culprit. Where are you declaring it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you by accident declare the variable 'outside the class'? This can lead to unexpected behaviour. Try to initialize all variables properly and see if the problem persists

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what had happened.